# create view across different databases?

Tags: mysql

If I have database test1 and database test2, and table employee1 under database test1 and table employee2 under database test2, is it possible to create a view of employee2 under database test1 in MySQL. If so, can you show me the syntax.

Both the databases are in the same machine.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: it is looks like [this][1].read this post carefully.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017612/how-do-i-create-a-mysql-view-that-reads-its-data-from-a-different-host-and-datab

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it as following:

```
CREATE VIEW `test1`.`new_employee` AS SELECT * FROM `test2`.`employee2 `;
```

Think it will help.

Comment: Its working fine for me, Just check your table name, It should be same as it is in DB.

Comment: i have huge table i want fetch some fields on this table is it possible?

Comment: have created view and now i added data in my original database now i want added data are sync or update my view ...

my query is ...

create view test1.view as select * from test2.name;

can you plz help me how to update my view..

Answer (score 0):

By database you mean database server (so they are different isntances of mysql), or just two databases on the same server?

For the latter, simply use the table name in the query:

```
CREATE VIEW db1.x AS SELECT * FROM db2.y  ...
```